# How can I refer to multiple items in a list while comparing it with another variable?

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I want to implement insertion sort where the number that is entered by the user is placed in ascending order in the list automatically. So far I have done this by comparing it with the last element in the list next to which it will be appended. How can I compare it with the whole list so as to place it in its appropriate position?

I'm using Python 3.

```
list = [25,3,14,17,36] 
a = int(input("enter"))  
list.append(a)
for n in list:
    if a < n:
        list = [a,n] 
print(list)    


>> [8, 36]
```

How can I output the rest of the list as well?

Comment: Is the result you show is what you get or is it what you desired to get?

Comment: Cheap fix: append the user input to list and sort by asc. "okay don't kill me"

Comment: `list = [a,n]` modifying the list while iterating over it, using the keyword `list`. all wronngggg!

Comment: what do you mean comparing? 8 can be less than every element of a list except 3 . so if we iterate it can be fit with most.. what is your desired output?

Comment: `lst.append(a)` appending the value to the list even before checking. Incorrect

Comment: I don't know what you think `list = [a,n]` does but it almost certainly does not do that.

Comment: list = [a, n ] will keep on override on each iterate.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. Are you looking for a way to swap two list elements?

Comment: Do you want to insert the element in the existing list? Then you should read about [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). I also would recommend to read about the built-in function [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Finally because you only want to insert it once you should read about the statement [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement).

Comment: I think this person is trying to insert the user input a, before an element, n, in his list. A couple things: 1. NEVER label your list "list". It will conflict with the list keyword in python. 2. Python has a lot of built-in list functions so for loops can be easily avoided. The answer: new_li = [x,y,z,n,m]. a = user_input. new_li .append(a). new_li .sort().

Comment: @DirtyBit That is the result I get.

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed list = [3, 8, 14,17,25,36] is the desired output in ascending order.

Comment: @SudaisAsif you just need sort then.. check my answer.. list.sort()

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes exactly swap them using bubble sort manually instead of any pre-defined function like sort().

Comment: @SvenKrüger That wouldn't automatically adjust it to ascending order neither would it automatically position itself in the list using .insert. Enumerate is something completely diff from what I'm trying to do I guess.

Comment: [Example](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBubbleSort.html) of a bubble sort implemented in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Ready to use recipes for inserting a new value into a SORTED list can be found in the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just need simple sort **list.sort()**,

i have added above line with your code.

```
me@me:/py$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = int(input("enter"))
enter8
>>> a
8
>>> list = [25,3,14,17,36]
>>> list.append(a)
>>> list
[25, 3, 14, 17, 36, 8]
>>> list.sort()
>>> list
[3, 8, 14, 17, 25, 36]
>>>
```

Comment: This is great, it accomplishes the purpose but the thing is, this would use the Timsort Algorithm which is a mixture of merge and insertion sort built into this function. However, if my exam tells me to use a bubble sort algorithm for sorting, I can't use this solution,hence I am trying to solve it manually.